# Reading information from two tables into two forms at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

For my first attempt at programming, I am making a simple webapp with php and MySQL, to enter customer information and store information about orders.

So far I've made a form to enter customer information, a page to edit that information and another page to show the different customers, which is all working fine.

I've run into a stump when trying to implement the next stage however.

I have an editcustomers page with 3 columns.

- Column 1 shows a form containing customer information, allowing it to
  be edited.
- Column 2 allows ordering of products and showing how many products were ordered
- Column 3 shows the total paid so far, and the total owing.

The code for the page I have at present:

```
<html>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
require_once('connect.php');
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM customers where id = '$id'");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
    <form name="myForm" action ="process.php" method ="post" >
    <?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){ ?>
    <p><input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" <?php echo $row["firstName"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["lastName"]?>"/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <?php }?>
    </div>

    <div id="mid">
    <p>Amount owed<br />
    <input type = "text" name ="moneyOwed" size ="30" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" /> 
    <p>Number of aaaa<br />
    <input type = "text" name ="numAaa" size ="30" /></p>
    <p>Number of bbbb<br />
    <input type = "text" name ="numBbb" size ="30" /></p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    <b>Total Balance</b>
    <p> Money owed: </p>
        <p> aaa total: </p>
    <p> bbb total: </p>
    <p> Total: </p>
    <input type = "text" name ="pay" size ="20" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" />
    </div>
<?php
$dbh =null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following database structure:

- A customers table, basic information like firstname, lastname, etc along with an id field.
- A products table, listing the different products, only 1 row containing the costs for each product.
- A purchases table, with an id field , fields like numProductA, numProductB, showing the quantity of each product ordered

The problem I'm having is that in my editcustomerspage, I have a database query to read in information from the customers table to fill the fields in the form in my first column and a separate query to update it if that if the function chosen.

Updating the second formshould be OK, as I could use a hidden field to differentiate forms, however I am unsure how to read the information in from the Customers table and from the Purchases table so that I can populate the fields in my second form..

Part of the problem is that the purchases table may be empty for a given customer, if that customer has not yet placed an order.

I was considering getting rid of the purchases table, and tacking the fields onto the users table which would solve my problem, although I think that is generally considered bad practice?

The products will be fixed in the application, and are not going to change. Even so, would it still be better to have column names cost and name and each products as  a record?

What are some approaches I could take to solving this problem?

Comment: I hope this question is not too broad for this site, my apologies if the question is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even what you currently are doing is considered bad practice because of the columns numProductA, numProductB. What happens when you'll have 1000 products and a user orders different amounts from all of them. This work only if the list of products is fixed (i.e. coded into the application) and requires a lot of coding.

You would probably want to create a purchase_item table that has fields like: id, purchase_id, product_id, num_product. It would be like a line on a standard bill: purchase_id identifies which bill the line belongs to; product_id would show the product that line is about and num_product would show the amount (multiplier) on that line.

In this manner you don't need to change the code when new products are added to the database.

Comment: Not sure how that is bad practice, there is never going to be more than four products, so yes the list is fixed. I don't need to have bills as such, just to be able to look up a customer and see the totals.

Answer (score 0):

Without a detailed description of the problems you've run into, it's hard to say how to fix them. It should be possible to implement what you want with the described design. However, you seem to be misunderstanding relational databases, which is why your database architecture is eyebrow-raising.

A database table is not a spreadsheet. While a table can have millions of rows, the number of columns is usually limited to a much smaller number. Even when the limit is not a problem, the way relational databases are designed does not lend itself well to storage of uniform data across a large number of columns. For example, your database won't be able to answer questions such as “what's the best-selling product”, “what products have been purchased by more than 100 customers”, etc.

The rule of thumb is that each table should contain a fixed number of columns. If you find that you'll have to add columns when you e.g. start selling new products, you're doing it wrong.

Here's what you should probably do in your application:

- `products` should be a table with one row per available product, containing, for each product, a unique `id`, the price and other information such as name, manufacturer etc.
- `purchases` should contain one row for every combination of (customer, product) where a customer has ordered the product. The row shouuld contain the customer id, the product id, and quantity ordered.

Using SQL, you can then easily construct a query that produces the set of products ordered by a specific customer. Using a join, this information can be enhanced with product names and prices.

Comment: The list of products is fixed and never going to be more than 4. Seeing history or being able to answer questions is not an issue and never will be. My concern is how to read information from two different tables into two different forms.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to say what the problem with that is. Just issue two SQL queries, and use their results in your forms.

Comment: I've revised my question, not sure if I can use a join as the Purchases table may not contain a corresponding record...

Comment: You shouldn't join if you insist on keeping your current database structure. Just request a row from purchases in a separate query.

Comment: I'm not meaning to insist on keeping the current structure, I just didn't want to have more than one record in the purchases table for each customer. I though having the prices in the products table and the number of products in the purchases table would allow the total to be calculated, and it seemed like the simplest way

Comment: What you are doing might be a tiny bit simpler, but very limited. I would not choose this solution even for the sake of simplicity.